# How does this "[.. for .. in ..]" work in Python?

Tags: python, list

Tell me please, how does it work exactly? Why does each iteration result write to array?

```
list_of_strings = [a.rstrip('\n') for a in list_of_strings]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This takes a list of strings (stored in variable `list_of_strings`), iterates through it assigning each string temporarily to variable `a` each time through and strips the `\n` character from each string. The result is a *list* of strings that is assigned back to the same variable.

This is using [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Generally most for-loops and [list operations involving append()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) can be converted to equivalent list comprehensions. Here's a simple example demonstrating this:

```
   new_list = []
   for i in range(10):
       new_list.append(i**2)
```

could be rewritten simply as

```
   new_list = [i**2 for i in range(10)]
```

You may find it instructive to take your list comprehension and rewrite it with a `for`-loop to test your understanding (both should produce identical results).

In most cases, list comprehension is faster than the equivalent `for`-loop and clearly a more compact way to express an algorithm. You can have nested list comprehensions too (just as you can have nested `for`-loops), but they can quickly become hard to comprehend :)

Also, while not shown in the code above, you can filter values in the list comprehension, i.e., including them (or not) in the resulting list depending on whether they meet some criteria.

As an aside, Python also provides similar set comprehensions and generator expressions. It's well worth learning about all of these.

Comment: "You can have nested list comprehensions too (just as you can have nested for-loops), but they can quickly become hard to comprehend" --> "list (in)comprehensions"?  :-)

Comment: @JS. .. yes, it can seem that way sometimes :)

Answer (score 5):

This [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_of_strings = [a.rstrip('\n') for a in list_of_strings]
```

is equivalent to this more generic code:

```
temp_list=[]
for a in list_of_strings:
   temp_list.append(a.rstrip('\n'))

list_of_strings=temp_list
```

In most cases, a list comprehension is faster and easier to read. Learn it and use it if you want to write nontrivial Python.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [An Introduction to List Comprehensions in Python](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html) to get a better understanding of Python's list comprehension syntax.

Answer (score 1):

each iteration result doesn't write to the list, instead an entirely new list is created on the right hand side and then assigned to the variable list_of_strings on the left hand side of the = sign.

Comment: It is not necessary to do a splice assignment. The result of the comprehension is rebound to `list_of_strings` AFTER iterating the original list and calculating the entire new list.

Comment: Ok thanks, Is the generator required however? _ I was told many years ago that a splice was required but I guess not then. What would happen if the list and generator had different lengths?

Comment: if you do the slice assignment, there is no real advantage to using a generator since you are generating the list at that time, no?

Comment: @drewk you *do* need the slice assignment if you do have a generator expression on the RHS instead of a list comp (otherwise you'll assign to the generator object, rather than putting its values into the list). You can do it with a listcomp RHS as well, of course. It does have a different effect than without the slice, but not in any way particular to listcomps - `mylist = [1, 2, 3]` and `mylist[:] = [1, 2, 3]` always behave differently if you've previously done something like 'another_list = mylist` - the slice changes the list rather than rebinding the name to a new list.

Comment: heh, yeah it would assign the generator otherwise, drewk made my lose confidence in myself lol, thanks for confirmation lvc

Comment: The comment is still the same: `l[:]=(x for x in l)` is somewhat wasteful. It is the same as `l=list(x for x in l)` which is probably less fast and direct than just using `l=[x for x in l]` and, in the later list comprehension form, no slice assignment is necessary.

Comment: try `python -m timeit 'l=range(10000);l=[x for x in l]'` vs `python -m timeit 'l=range(10000);l[:]=(x for x in l)'` The first is more than 2X faster on my computer...  :-) Cheers!

Comment: It's more about saving memory. One could run out of memory using the 1st. Also if it was (x for x in connection_packets), we have to wait for each packet anyway, so the later is faster

Comment: But that is the thing! You are saving no memory in this case at all! The entire list will be created from the generator -- no differently than calling `list(generator)`  each form (generator expression vs list comprehension) has its place.

Comment: I just tested this (in python 2.7). You are correct, my mistake. >>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def f():
...     print x
...     yield 5
...     print x
...     yield 6
...     print x
...     yield 7
...     print x
...
>>> x[:] = f()

Comment: @drewk `l[:] = (x for x in j)` (or, `l[:] = j`) isn't the same as `l = list(j)`, but *is* the same as `l[:] = list(j)` (though you are right that the memory difference here is tiny). List slice assignment *changes that list* rather than rebinding the variable to a new list. Try `k = l = range(10); l = [2*x for x in l]; print k` and then the same with the slice assignment. Also, `list(generator)` is neither less direct nor less fast than the equivalent listcomp - in fact, in newer Python versions, I believe they compile to the same bytecode.

Comment: @lvc: Agreed, but the effect HERE is the same. `l[:]=`*gen sequence* changes the existing list `l` and `l=list(gen seq)` creates and binds a new list. Agreed. However -- both consume the entire gen sequence before assignment. There is no memory savings. A more complete description would be `LHS = TEMP_LIST = Sequence` with the entire sequence being consumed by the temp list. You cannot limit the sequence with something like `gen=xrange(20); l[2:5]=gen` and have elements left over in gen. The whole sequence is used by the assignment to `l[2:5]` and the length of the sequence is not limited.

Comment: @drewk indeed, there is no reason to prefer slice assignment of a generator expression to normal assignment of a list comprehension here. I disagree that there would be *no* memory saved - the list itself does use some memory aside from its elements - but certainly the saving wouldn't be remotely noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Python called list comprehensions. Basically, what you write in the brackets is shorthand for 'do this loop and then create a list of the results'.

Answer (score 0):

**List Comprehensions have the following generic form**

```
result = [ x for x in list]
```

the equivalent procedural code for this list comprehension is:

```
for x in list:
    x
```

**The next step in creating a useful list comprehensions is calling or applying a function to the first x after the bracket.**

```
result = [function(x) for x in list]
result = [x.function(arg) for x in list]

list_of_strings = [a.rstrip('\n') for a in list_of_strings]

result = [x*2 for x in list_of_numbers]
```

the equivalent procedural code for this list comprehension is:

```
for x in list:
    function(x)
```

OR

```
for x in list:
    x.function()
```

**To add more power to your list comprehensions you can add conditionals like this:**

```
result = [function(x) for x in list if x == True]

list_of_strings = [a.rstrip('\n') for a in list_of_strings if '\n' in a]

result = [x*2 for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] if x > 3]
```

List Comprehensions make great filter like functions and are often as fast as the hard c coded primitives like map and filter in cpython.