# If statement with no else branch while making array with for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I want to create an array inline like this:
`[x if arr[arr.index(x)+1] < x for x in arr]` but when i do it python tells me i cant do that without having an else branch to my if statement.

The only "solution" I found was this: `list(filter(lambda x: x != None, [x if arr[arr.index(x)+1] < x else None for x in arr])` but that is just ugly, and unnessecary. The reason i want to initialize the array this way is to keep the code short and clean, but now it would just be better to do a normal for loop.

Hopefully there are better ways to do this ;)

Comment: post example input and expected output?

Comment: `[x  for x in arr if arr[arr.index(x)+1] < x]`. No idea if that actually makes sense to me, but the `if` condition comes at the end if it's not accompanied by an `else`.

Comment: What if there are duplicate items in `arr`? `index` will only find the first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does this "\[.. for .. in ..\]" work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875364/how-does-this-for-in-work-in-python)

Comment: Doesn't this crash on the last element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: Disagree with the dupes, I think this is better served by numpy syntax but we don't have enough context

Comment: Are you actually using numpy arrays or just python lists here? "Arrays" 99% of the time refers to numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` is in the wrong position to correctly implement `filter()` with a list comprehension. Try this instead:

```
[x for x in arr if arr[arr.index(x)+1] < x]
```

See [list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter) for details.

Comment: This crashes with `arr = [1, 3, 2, 4]` with `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @PeterWood Good point. I was only showing how to fix the syntax error from the OP's code. I didn't worry about testing if this fix reveals a logic error. I leave the fix as an exercise for the OP and any other reader.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through pairs from the list:

```
[a for a, b in zip(arr, arr[1:])
 if a < b]
```

For example:

```
>>> arr = [1, 3, 2, 4]
>>> [a for a, b in zip(arr, arr[1:])
...  if a < b]
[1, 2]
```

The accepted answer crashes with these values:

```
>>> [x for x in arr if arr[arr.index(x)+1] < x]
Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution that seems to almost match what the OP is doing. Note that this will eliminate the last element of the list because `zip()` terminates on the shortest of the input lists. This may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The only way OP's code (and your fixed solution) wouldn't crash is if the last element was duplicated earlier in `arr`. But then the solution would be wrong as `index` would find the earlier value.